# Variables defined in a function - Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I am running this code: https://dpaste.de/RiAP

As you see, the variable `linespecificpayload` is used only within this function, but if I check the ID, its the same in every function call.

I can't seem to figure out how to flush its value with each call. Both the call for `id(linespecificpayload)` return the same value. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Also the code is something I wrote in an hour or two. So may not be the most efficient one.

Comment: Why would you want to flush it?

Comment: `linespecificpayload` is declared and assigned with a global variable `filespecificpayload` ... so the call to `id(linespecificpayload)` will result in the same value.

Comment: In each function call, the JSON structure of linespecificpayload is modified, and passed to a web API. For each call, I would like to start with a fresh copy.

Comment: @DOOM kroolik has suggested the same that I am not copying the value but the reference from the global variable. I am not sure how to copy the value.

Comment: @gattaga seems like you are not aware of how `python` assigns and creates variable .. look at [Python and Pointers](http://tharindu-rusira.blogspot.de/2012/09/python-and-pointers.html)

Comment: That link helps a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are assigning a global object to `linespecificpayload`, thus the reference stays the same.

If you would like to create a copy of the `filespecificpayload` dict you can either:

- use `filespecificpayload.copy()`. This will create a copy of the dict, but the values that existed before copying will be shared so that  `id(filespecificpayload[key]) == id(filespecificpayload.copy()[key])`
- use `copy.deepcopy()`:

  ```
  >>> from copy import deepcopy
  >>> d = deepcopy(filespecificpayload)
  >>> id(d[key]) == id(filespecificpayload[key])
  False
  ```

Comment: How do I make it so linespecificpayload copies the value, and not the reference of filespecificpayload

Comment: If `filespecificpayload` is a regular dict, you can use `filespecificpayload.copy()` to create another dict with the same objects as values, or `from copy import deepcopy; deepcopy(filespecificpayload)` to perform a full-blown copy.